# Change behavior of geometry for all pages

Tags: margins, double-sided, geometry, lncs

I'm using the `llncs` document class and wanted to change the margin of all pages, using the `geometry` package.

I use the following command:

```
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

The problem is that the left margin is switching between odd and even pages. Even numbered pages have the 'left' margin on the right side and the odd numbered pages have the 'left' margin on the actual left side.

I don't know if this is a problem with `llncs` or `geometry` (thus, the title could be misleading), but how would I tell my document to have the left margin on the actual left side, for every page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `llncs` class loads the `article` class with the `twoside` option and doesn't have a `oneside` option. You can revert back to "oneside" by switching manually:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@twosidetrue\@twosidefalse
\let\@mparswitchtrue\@mparswitchfalse
\makeatother

\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: Ah! I see. I changed it directly in the `llncs.cls` file now.